# Need help using randomly generated numbers in a formula using R

Tags: r, random, montecarlo

This is my code below and all I get is a list of the same values and it doesn't seem like R is taking a randomly generated value, running through the equation and then giving me the results.

```
montecarlo = function(r,v,t,x,k,n) {
   y = rnorm(n)
   stockprice = x*exp((-v*sqrt(t)*y)+((r-(.5*v^2))*t))
   MCOP = exp(-r*t)*(stockprice-k)
   return(MCOP)
}
```

The output for this code is just a single value 100 times if I set n = 100

Comment: What are the other values you're passing to the call? Setting these arbitrarily I am able to produce `n=100` values. Possible you're reducing the function down to a limiting case?

Comment: Setting `montecarlo(n = 100, r = 1, v = 1, x = 1, t = 1, k = 1)` results in `n = 100` different values

Comment: What values did you enter for r,v,t,x,k?    When I enter    ` montecarlo(1,2,3,4,5,10)`   I get different values.

Comment: This is the command I give montecarlo(45,65,1,30,29,100)

Comment: I also use .45 in some cases like montecarlo(.45,65,1,30,29,100)

Comment: @dyermako - notice that they're all _extremely_ small values (-8.301304e-19)? You're taking `exp(-65)` -- it's going to be a small result.

Comment: @dyermako even `montecarlo(45,1,1,30,29,100)` gives some variation.

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan you were right it was a limiting case

Answer (score 1):

Let's add some `print()` statements (you could also do this by using `debug(montecarlo)` to step through the function interactively):

```
montecarlo = function(r,v,t,x,k,n) {
   y = rnorm(n)
   p = (-v*sqrt(t)*y)+((r-(.5*v^2))*t)
   print(range(p))
   stockprice = x*exp(p)
   print(range(stockprice))   
   MCOP = exp(-r*t)*(stockprice-k)
   return(MCOP)
}
```

Now try the function:

```
set.seed(101)
m <- montecarlo(.45,65,1,30,29,100)
[1] -2232.440 -1961.294  ## exponent values
[1] 0 0                  ## stockprice values
```

So the exponents are of such large (negative) magnitude that the exponential function underflows to zero.  Since the random values enter the expression only through `stockprice`, they are zeroed out.

It looks like the main culprit here is `v`, which you have set to 65, so `v^2` is a large number ...

Comment: Thank you Ben I've figured it out and you're right, some of those values need to be smaller

Comment: While the sentiment is appreciated, StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.